# 3d Figures giving some error in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

So, a python newbie here. What I'm trying to do is to plot point onto 3d plane. Although some errors occur at execution.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()

chart = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1,projection='3d')

X,Y,Z=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[2,5,3,8,9,5,6,1],[3,6,2,7,5,4,5,6]

chart.plot_wireframe(X,Y,Z)

plt.show()
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nishantsikri/3d objects.py", line 10, in <module>
chart.plot_wireframe(X,Y,Z)
  File "/home/nishantsikri/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py", line 1834, in plot_wireframe
    if Z.ndim != 2:
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

Comment: @Alessandro Since you cannot put a 1D array into a plot_wireframe, I strongly doubt that.